AWS Cognito Federated Sign-In Error with Google NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool
I am developing a React Native Expo app using AWS Amplify and I'm trying to implement federated sign-in with Google using Expo's expo-auth-session. I have configured the Google client IDs for iOS, Android, and Web in the Google Developer Console and added them to the AWS Cognito Identity Pool through AWS-Amplify. However, I'm facing an issue during the sign-in process.
Error Received:
Error during federated sign in: [NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool.]

Problem Description:
I successfully retrieve the ID token and access token from Google, but when I attempt to use these tokens for federated sign-in with Cognito, I get the above error. Upon decoding the ID token, I noticed that the aud (audience) claim matches the iOS client ID, which is different from the Web client ID I have registered in the Cognito Identity Pool.
Configuration Details:

I have different client IDs for each platform (iOS, Android, Web) configured in Google Developer Console.
Only the Web client ID is registered in AWS Cognito.

Redirect URL Settings:
I'm using npx expo run:ios for local testing, and my OAuth 2.0 settings in Google Cloud are configured with:

Authorized JavaScript origins: https://auth.expo.io
Authorized redirect URIs: https://auth.expo.io/@owner/slug

Is this configuration correct for handling the OAuth flow in a local development environment using Expo?
Code Snippet:
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

// Configuration for Google Auth
const clientId = Platform.select({
  ios: 'IOS_CLIENT_ID', // example: '1gargc5.apps.googleusercontent.com'
  android: 'ANDROID_CLIENT_ID',
  web: 'WEB_CLIENT_ID'
});

const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
  clientId: clientId
});

// Function to handle the sign-in process
async function signInWithGoogle(token, name, email) {
  try {
    const user = await Auth.federatedSignIn(
      'google',
      {
        token,
        expires_at: 3600 * 1000 + new Date().getTime()
      },
      { name, email }
    );
    console.log('Credentials obtained:', user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during federated sign in:', error);
  }
}

Questions:

Is it required to have the same Google client ID for all platforms in AWS Cognito? If so, how can I configure this properly?
Could the mismatch between the aud claim in the ID token and the client ID registered in Cognito be the reason for the NotAuthorizedException error?
Are the redirect URL settings correct for local development with Expo, or do I need to adjust them?
Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions!
